# comando para realizar uma chamada do telefone

Tags: html

Então, estou tentando colocar uma imagem onde a pessoa clica e comece uma ligacação, e neste código devo inserir o telefone, para direcionar. Faz parte de um app mobile, estou fazendo numa pagina html e não manjo nada vcs podem me ajudar?

---

Comment: Com qual linguagem está sendo feito esse app?

Answer (score 2):

Olá, faça assim.

```
<a href="tel:+9999999999"><img src"" alt""></a>
```

Comment: A tag `img` não precisa ser fechada (e nem pode, em HTML normal, sem ser XHTML).